# Adding small values to very large number doesn't appear to change number, R

Tags: r

When I take the product of even integers from 2 to 40 in R, adding small numbers to the product doesn't appear to change the number.

So, getting that value with a for loop:

```
sum <- 1
for (i in 1:20){
j <- i*2
sum <- sum*j
}
> sum
[1] 2.551083e+24
```

Then, when I add numbers, the logical equivalence operator tells me the number isn't changing, e.g.

```
> sum == sum + 1
[1] TRUE

> sum == sum + 1e3
[1] TRUE
> sum == sum + 1e8
[1] TRUE
> sum == sum + 1e9
[1] FALSE
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Floating point numbers have a limited precision.

Comment: The same reason `1 == 1.0000000000000001` is `TRUE`

Comment: Also see the help page for `?print` and notice the digits argument although that would not have solve this concern.

Comment: If you want to make comparisons, look into "Rmpfr" package. It helps you make higher precision evaluations/comparisons.